# How can I stop the React buttons from rendering synchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

Every time I click the "increase" or "decrease" buttons for a certain player, I want the score to increase for that player only. However, right now when I click either of the buttons it increases both scores. I know it is probably something simple that I am completely overlooking, but any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!
Here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-curran-6ogn3?file=/src/App.js:0-2090:

`import "./styles.css";
import {Component, useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [playerScore, setplayerScore] = useState([{
    nameOne: 'Player 1'
  }, {
    nameTwo: 'Player 2'
  }
]);

  const increase = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setplayerScore(playerScore);
  };

  const decrease = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
    setplayerScore(playerScore);
  };

  return (
    <main>
    {/* player 1*/}
      <div>
          {playerScore.map((player) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h2 className="name">{player.nameOne}</h2>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="score">{count}</div>
        {/* increase button */}
          <button onClick={increase}>
            Increase
          </button>

        {/* decrease button */}
          <button onClick={decrease}>
            Decrease
          </button>
      </div>

    {/* player 2 */}
    <div>
          {playerScore.map((player) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h2 className="name">{player.nameTwo}</h2>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="score">{count}</div>
        <section>
          <button onClick={increase}>Increase</button>
          <button onClick={decrease}>Decrease</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this fork based on your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hooks-q9ntu?file=/src/App.js

I have refactored some logic and added the functionality that I understand you want. Specially the increase/decrease logic.

The main error was that you were using same state for the entire array, so the value will always be the same for all the items.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! That is exactly the functionality that I wanted. I guess I need to study React states a little more :)